# MongoDB default values are not saved, instead re-calculated at runtime

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a simple REST app on the Yeoman Express MVC generator with MongoDB.

This is my MongoDB/Mongoose model (**updated with complete `update.js` model**):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UpdateSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    text: String,
    authors: String,
    url: String,
    imageUrl: String,
    dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    reloadNeeded: { type: Boolean, default: true }
});

mongoose.model('Update', UpdateSchema);
```

This is what the data looks like in the Mongo client:

```
> db.updates.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5476453f8920d05ecdef4eec"), "title" : "Hello World", "text" : "yoda yoda" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547653748920d05ecdef4eed"), "title" : "Hihi", "text" : "mookie" }
```

And this is the JSON output from my Express app:

```
[
    {"_id":"5476453f8920d05ecdef4eec","title":"Hello World","text":"yoda yoda","reloadNeeded":true,"dateCreated":"2014-11-27T10:50:10.078Z"},
    {"_id":"547653748920d05ecdef4eed","title":"Hihi","text":"mookie","reloadNeeded":true,"dateCreated":"2014-11-27T10:50:10.078Z"}
]
```

So, `dateCreated` and `reloadNeeded` are set **at runtime** - but I'd rather want them set (and persisted) when I create the documents. What's going on?

---

**Update:** seems like values *are* persisted if I create from Mongoose rather than the MongoDB shell.

Comment: Mongoose defaults are definitely persisted at document creation, but if the docs already exist it won't add them.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Do I need to do something to make sure my model changes are enforced?

Comment: Update: seems like values _ARE_ persisted if I create from Mongoose rather than the MongoDB shell.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use mongoose for data model? If it so, default values will be created on document construction http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/defaults.html

Anyway I assume the reason is in defaults